# Marking old questions as active by author

Tags: feature-request, questions, unanswered-questions

It would be nice to allow author to mark his/her old question as active (awaiting answer).

Some people may treat old question without answers as forgotten or solved outside stack sites.

Answer (score 10):

You can already do this. You can *edit* your question.

When you do this, only do so when you have new details to add; perhaps you tried something else that didn't solve the problem either. Editing your question "bumps" it up the homepage again.

You can also offer a bounty on the question to draw attention, provided you have at least 75 reputation.

Also see [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: I have offered bounty without effect. I have nothing to add. The question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310574/how-to-generate-dynamic-reply-to-based-on-message-id-detail

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip if adding a bounty didn't work, why do you think that adding something saying "this question is active" will?

Comment: I would like a cleaner solution. I may use your suggestion as a "stack offers nothing better/good" fix.

Comment: Your question is already listed as 'unanswered', as it has no upvoted answers. It'll get bumped automatically by Community User from time to time. If you have nothing to add and another (larger) bounty still doesn't get you an answer, consider the possibility that *there is no answer*. Adding yet another feature is not going to improve your chances here.

Answer (score 0):

If no one answered while you had a bounty going on, it's likely that either:

1. no one who saw it during the week it was featured knew an answer or
2. the bounty was too small for someone who knew to bother answering a complicated question.

In either case, offering a new, larger county may attract answers. Showing some of your own attempted code may also help by reducing the burden of coding a solution.

You should make sure the question has all the relevant tags, because most users looking for questions to answer will use some tags to filter out ones they know how to answer. For example, your question might need the [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) tag if that's a large part of the problem (sorry, I don't know how emacs scripting works) and a typical follower of that tag might be able to solve it.